# "process launch failed: failed to get the task for process" with adhoc app

Tags: ios, parse-platform

My app runs perfectly with the developmental provisional profile, but the moment I tried to use a adhoc profile it crashes.

I have been following the tutorial on parse for push notification for the transition from development to ad hoc. 
I have made a new production certificate for the push notification settings, uploaded the new p12 certificate to parse. Then I also made a new adhoc provisioning profile.

In the build settings of the app I have set the provisioning profile to the new adhoc one. The code signing identity is now also assigned to "iphone distribution etc" instead of "iphone developer", is this where I've gone wrong? But the "iphone Distribution" identity is the identity available from my ad hoc provisional profile.

Have been stuck on this for a day. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to get the crash report from the device and symbolicate it.

Comment: is the crash report available from the debug area?

Answer (score 0):

Try archiving the project, export and ipa file and install that on the phone and see if it runs.